# Diagonal Matrix Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that a diagonal matrix is positive definite if and only if all
>   its diagonal entries are positive. Also write down and identify its
>   associated inner product. (I can't use eigenvalues to prove this
>   because I haven't learned them yet).

My attempt:

In order to be positive definite, matrix K must be symmetric and satisfy positivity. Since we have a diagonal matrix and all its diagonal entries are positive its determinant will be positive as well as its leading coefficient, but how can I show all this information formally using a proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $K$ is diagonal, it is of the form $K=\mathrm{diag}(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$ for some real $k_i$. Let $x=(x_i)$ be a real $n\times 1$ vector; then

$$x^TKx = \sum_{1\leq i\leq n} k_i x_i^2$$

is the inner product associated with $K$.

Since $K$ is positive definite, we have that $x^TKx>0$ for all nonzero $x$. Suppose that some diagonal entry $k_{d}\leq 0$.  Then if we take an $x$ such that $x_d=1$ and other components of $x$ are zero, then $x^TKx = k_{d}x_d^2 <0$. This contradicts the fact that $K$ is positive definite.

The converse should be fairly easy and proceed along similar lines.

Note:$K$ need not be symmetric to be positive definite.

Comment: Hmm, so I should try and prove this question by contradiction?

Comment: Well, that's one possible route

Comment: How did you know proving by contradiction was the easy route?

Comment: I have studied this proof!

Comment: haha :). This is my first semester learning proofs and I am very raw it at. Just wanted to know .. Thank you very much though!